# Solving differential equation with given variable substitutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I have $$yf'_x-xf'_y=0$$ and should solve it using the variable substitutions $$u=x^2+y^2, v=x$$

I have managed to get $$f'_x=2xf'_u+f'_v$$ and $$f'_y=2yf'_u$$ through the chain rule.

This in the original equation gives me $$yf'_v=0$$

The solution provided is as below but I don't understand it.

So $f=h(u)=h(x^2+y^2)$ where $h$ $C'$ function of a variable. (Handwritten, might have typos)

I need help with understanding what the suggested solution means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your variables $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=x$ you have a simplified equation:
$$y\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=0$$
Since this equation must always hold (for any arbitrary value of $y$) the derivative of $f$ wrt. $v$ must be zero, and therefore $f$ must be a function of $u$ only:
$$f=h(u) = h(x^2+y^2)$$

Another approach is:

You can put your equation for $f(x,y)$:
$$ y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0\tag{*}$$
 as the total derivative of $f$ wrt. some parameter $t$ supposing:
$$x=x(t) \qquad y=y(t)$$
 equated to $0$. This is:
$$\frac{df(x(t),y(t))}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}=0\tag{**}$$

You can immediately see that equations $(*)$ and $(**)$ have a lot in common, and they are identical iff:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=-x$$ 
The latter equations can be multiplied by $x$ and $y$ respectively and adding them toguether gives:
$$ x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(x^2+y^2\right) = 0$$

Therefore the taryectories described by curves on $xoy$ plane such as $x^2+y^2$ have a constant $f$ throughout the motion. Therefore, by equation $(**)$ the function $f$ must be a function of $x^2+y^2$, namely $f=h(x^2+y^2)$ since

$$\frac{df(x,y)}{dt} = h'(x,y)\frac{d}{dt}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=0$$

Comment: Thank you, that helps me to understand how to get to h(u). However, I still fail at understanding what "where h C′ function of a variable." means in the solution provided by the tutor.

Comment: Could it be $h\in C^1$?

Comment: Yeah, might be. It is a scanned handwritten solution. Would that mean that h is in a one dimensional range C? From the constant C introduced when integrating? Or why is it denoted by C?

Comment: Or is it just saying that h is on the curve C.

Comment: I am not sure...I can say only that $f=constant$ along curves $x^2+y^2=R^2$ for $R\in\mathbb{R}$